# Nesting a function returning NaN

Tags: javascript, function, counter, calculator

I am running into an error when I try nesting a simple counter function inside an existing function. I know some people frown upon this, so if there is any other way of doing this, it would be greatly appreciated. Basically, I am calling a function to parse a JSON string to get 3 numbers. I would like to animate those 3 numbers with a counter every time a new calculation is made. My instinct is to place this counter function inside of the same for loop that runs to get the numbers themselves. Doing so returns NaN. I'm sure there is something very little that I am missing here that I am hoping someone can pick up on.

Code:

```
var text = '{JSON data}'
var obj = JSON.parse(text);

function calculate() {
    var e = document.getElementById("ltSpecialtyList");
    var selectedSpec = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    console.log(selectedSpec);

    var x = document.getElementById("ltLocationList");
    var selectedState = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;
    console.log(selectedState);

    for (i = 0; i < obj.values.length; i++)
    {
        if (obj.values[i].State == selectedState && obj.values[i].Specialty == selectedSpec)
        {
            // DISPLAY RESULTS DIV (JQUERY)
            var $resultsDiv = $("#ROI-results");
            $resultsDiv.fadeIn();

            // CAPTURE HEADER SPAN NAMES
            var headerState = document.getElementById("header-state-name");
            var headerSpec = document.getElementById("header-specialty-name");
            // CLEAR STATE AND SPECIALTY FROM SPAN
            headerState.innerHTML = "";
            headerSpec.innerHTML = "";
            // ADD SELECTED STATE AND SPECIALTY
            headerState.innerHTML += selectedState;
            headerSpec.innerHTML += selectedSpec;

            // CAPTURE RESULT DATA DIVS
            var permResults = document.getElementById("ROI-results-perm-data");
            var locumResults = document.getElementById("ROI-results-locums-data");
            var uncollectedResults = document.getElementById("ROI-results-uncollected-data");
            // CLEAR DATA DIVS
            permResults.innerHTML = "";
            locumResults.innerHTML = "";
            uncollectedResults.innerHTML = "";
            //POPULATE DIV WITH DATA
            permResults.innerHTML += "<p class='ROI-results-data-number univers-bold'>" + obj.values[i].Permanent + "</p>";
            locumResults.innerHTML += "<p class='ROI-results-data-number univers-bold'>" + obj.values[i].Locums + "</p>";
            uncollectedResults.innerHTML += "<p class='ROI-results-data-number univers-bold'>" + obj.values[i].Gross + "</p>";
        }

        // COUNTER
        $('.ROI-results-data-number').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
                Counter: $(this).text()
            }, {
                duration: 4000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function (now) {
                    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                }
            });
        });
    } 
}
```

Comment: could you please note which variable is returned as NAn.

Comment: I'd like to know which function returns anything, there's no return statement at all in the code, in any of the 3 functions

Comment: are you sure this is a minimal example that reproduces your issue? (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) I guess, since you already control everything via console, you may just set your values and create static html and try the nested function only

Comment: Based on what you want to do, this is pretty inefficient. The animation will happen on every iteration of the for loop. I would move it outside of the loop, get the numbers, and then animate.

Comment: The convention of using capitalized first letters (even for object properties) for constructor functions only is pretty strong in JavaScript, that's going to likely confuse anyone else who has to read your code.